# JavaScript Intellisense with Visual Studio Code: How to get it to work for required modules?

Tags: node.js, intellisense, visual-studio-code, require

For some reason, intellisense won’t work for me for required modules. At least out-of-the box. For example (this is JS code):

```
const fs = require(‘fs’);
```

won’t kick intellisense when typing:

```
fs.
```

further down the code.

However, if I install "some" modules in the project’s node_modules directory (running the $ npm install command), I will get intellisense to work *after* bouncing it. Regardless of which modules were installed (apparently).

Even more puzzling, removing the node_modules altogether will make intellisense continue to work. Even bouncing VS Code won’t affect intellisense, which will continue to work from this point onward.

It looks like installing "some" modules somehow fixed whatever wasn’t right for intellisense. Question is, where is this fix living? In a file? And what is it?

PS: I am using VS Code version 1.7.2 with Node 6.5.0, on Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

- First check if you have [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) in your source folder
- Then install [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings)
- With **typings** now you can install the dt package.
  Search for the node version you need, command line: **typings search node**.
  Install with something like: `typings install dt~node --global --save`
- Just in case reopen vscode.

Comment: Thanks, Hosar. I did what you said (created `jsconfig.json` file and installed `typings` module) and here's the outcome: VS Code says, just after bouncing it = "The workspace folder contains TypeScript version 2.1.4. Do you want to use this version instead of the bundled version 2.0.10?". If I say Yes, i.e. if I use version 2.1.4 which comes with the downloaded `typings` module, I *do* get intellisense to work. Great! Having said that, I don't understand this pre-bundled version thing... which does not seem to work?

Comment: Not sure I was having the same issue. This was the way to fix it. As a bonus you can have intellisense for other packages like `mocha`  and   `chai` installing the corresponding typing.

Comment: Quick update: I can confirm that I can get intellisense to work by simply installing a module (e.g. `npm install socket.io`), and then closing my project folder / reopening it from within VS Code. I need to experiment further to fully wrap my head around this. Thanks, Hosar.

Comment: Other update: I just need to install the Typescript module. `npm install typescript`. This installs only *one* module (Typescript), and then when I bounce VS Code I just need to confirm that I indeed want to use Typescript version 2.1.4 instead of bundled version 2.0.10 and I'm all set.